# Search Issues on MacOS

Tags: safari, ms-office, spotlight, search

For the past 2-3 months, I am having a weird issue on my Macbook Air. I was hoping if someone here can help me out.

First, spotlight stopped searching on my mac. In the picture below, I am searching for Sublime app on my machine but it only shows results from the web. [image: Spotlight Search]

Second, search in outlook stopped working. No matter what I search, it always returned with no results found. In the image below, there should be many emails which has invoice in subject or body but it just shows no results.

[image: Outlook Search]

Finally today, search bar in Safari started behaving weirdly. Typing here used to bring in my bookmarks but they don't come up. Even the enter key doesn't work.

A lot of my productivity has been hampered by this. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thank you.

[Edit] The issue for safari was resolved after I restarted my mac.

Comment: This doesn't look like iOS, it's macOS.  Please update your title.  There's a few similar questions here about Spotlight searches and results.  Have you looked at those answers and tried them yet?  Those would be the starting point for any troubleshooting.

Comment: Looks like different issues with no common cause. For Spotlight, go to System Preferences → Spotlight and see if the appropriate categories are selected. You should also consider [rebuilding](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201716) Spotlight index. Search not working in Outlook and Safari are independent from Spotlight IMO.

Comment: @fsb Thank you. I have updated the title. It was my bad.

Comment: @NimeshNeema The issue for Outlook and Spotlight happened on the same date so I believe they are related in someway. I did look at rebuilding the spotlight search but it didn't work. I will give it another try today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a temporary issue that cannot be reproduced and was fuxed with a reboot. Question is not useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: Concerning Outlook, have a look at my recent answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354327/45492. Also there are numerous Qs & As here that deal with Spotlight not working properly, e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/62715/45492. Did you try them, in particular rebuilding the the Spotlight index?