# MacBook HD "Other" all of a sudden almost full

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

As you can see in the below image, my HD "Other" category is almost full. A couple of days ago, I randomly kept getting a popup saying that my disk was almost full. Then I went in and noticed the issue in the image. I ran the repair disk utility and got all my software up to date, to no avail. Haven't found any help on Google. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Interesting... Just had a look on this page. Never knew that I had 13.54 EB (1 Exabyte = 1,000,000 TB) of movies and videos...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Comment: @Mark I'd say no - one is more about what process and other tools can measure things. This could be a temporary issue or a bug or a call for other tools. Let's leave both open for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether you've already found this, but there are a number of other people having the same issue on the [Apple Discussion Groups](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3303747?start=0&tstart=0). There seems to be quite a lot of good information in that thread so I recommend reading it through, but the consensus seems to be that its hidden local backups/snapshots that's causing it.

A few people also used [DaisyDisk](http://daisydiskapp.com/) to find, then delete, hidden space on the hard disk.

Comment: I second the recommendation of DaisyDisk - it's a fantastic product.

Answer (score 1):

I've also noticed on my copy of Lion that it lists anything as "Other" that it doesn't identify to be part of OSX's categorisations. For example I have 25GB of mkv files in my Movies folder, but OSX only sees as me having 7.46GB of movies...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and finally found the cause of the problem. My mail app had issues connecting to one of my email accounts and I found it was storing all of the error messages (900+ GB worth).

Check to see if your having the same problem:

- Open finder
- press command, shift, g
- type      ~/Library
- press go
- locate & check the size of your mail folder (mine was 900+ GB!!!)
- delete files

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't use mac mail, but I will check other folders though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting up from the recovery partition and repairing the disk in Disk Utility? [That just solved a similar issue I was having](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/44877/3936).

Comment: Yeah, didn't help though

Answer (score 1):

Try this delete unnecessary (old) mobile device backups:

- In iTunes, go Preferences/Devices and view your device backups
- Delete unneeded copies of device back ups.

Depending on the number of iOS upgrades you did in the past this will regain a bunch of GBs.

Comment: 229 GB are used with "other", do you really think deleting a few mobile device backups of 5-10 GB (for large ones) help here?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have a bundle image on this drive that is always mounted?

Although not full these can only be shrunk when unmounted - and therefore it might just keep growing...

Answer (score 0):

Try [OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidisksweeper/), to see a hierarchical view of your entire HDD (or partition) based on the files and folders size.

> OmniDiskSweeper is really great at what it does: showing you the files on your drive, in descending order by size, and letting you delete them easily!

And it’s free.

Answer (score 0):

This also can be a temporary situation.

I've been doing a lot of restoring of Time Machine backups to new machines and for a handful of minutes to a several hours after the restore is done, this tool reports other when in reality a good chunk of space should (and will eventually) be shown to be music, apps and movies.

[image]

The picture above looked very similar to yours when I first checked. Unlike spotlight, which shows indexing progress and will incrementally refine search results as new space and files are indexed, System Information takes a momentary snapshot. If you leave that window open and come back in a day - it won't have changed, but if you quit and re-open it, you should see the categorization completed and a truer representation of space.

So, I would also suspect that sometimes the process storing this data could be buggy and a reboot/reinstall/other might be needed to clean things up and re-start the process that determines which file type is using space.

Answer (score 0):

I have been manually backing up files from a dying MBP and noticed 49GB+ of images in **~/Library/Container/com.apple.Preview/Data** folder. Some of these images were over 2 years old. I'd recommend digging through the folders inside the containers and see what other applications have created copies of your files.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is thread is old, but I was experiencing the same problem on my Macbook Pro on El Capitan. Using OmniDiskSweeper was awesome but I found the high quality transcoded media files from Final Cut Pro X were massive, so I did a huge project clean up and it gave me an extra 200gb of free space.

Comment: How does this improve on other answers - it might be better to edit them