# Finder not showing correct free space?

Tags: macos, finder, disk-space

I have a software called *Daisy Disk* and it says I only have **70 GB** left in my drive. However in *Finder* I see **131 GB** available.

How is this 60 GB difference possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk)

Comment: @Mark That question is talking about Daisy Disk's 'hidden space' category, and the OP has even *already* disabled local snapshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finder does not take into account Time Machine's Local Snapshots. The storage space of these local snapshots will be given to files if necessary and therefore the space is not actually being consumed. Daisy Disk sees these files though and takes them into account when calculating the free space.

You can disable local snapshots by turning off Time Machine completely, or to retain Time Machine functionality without local snapshots you can run the following command:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

Comment: How can I disable local snapshots?

Comment: @Koray I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how can I delete them as well?

Comment: @Koray Disabling them will slowly delete them (as fast as possible without taking up too much CPU).