# Hidden files taking up hard disc space?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, storage

I’ve used DaisyDisk to analyse my file usage on my MacBook Pro (mid–2012), but the numbers aren’t adding up. Of 500GB, it shows ~425GB used, but the breakdown only adds up to 280GB. The diagram itself shows a big gap, so what’s going on? What else can I use to track down this drive usage? I’ve attached a screen grab of my DaisyDisk analysis.

[image: Screengrab of DaisyDisk analysis]

Using the Disk utility and the Storage tab from *About this Mac* doesn’t reveal anything useful either, see following screen grabs:

[image: Screen grab from About this Mac]

Comment: One of these answer might help you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk

Comment: Are you running DaisyDisk as an admin user? If not, see if the results are different when you do.

Comment: The existence of the `lost+found` directory indicates an issue with your file system. Back-up your hard drive and run disk utility from the Recovery partition or run fsck in single user mode.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Joonas’ lead got me to the right place. Doing a scan as an admin helped, but it wasn’t apparent that was possible as I was using a version of the app downloaded from the Mac App Store. For anyone reading this later, the developers have made it easy to switch to a version from their own site that permits scanning the entire Mac HD as an admin.