# More than 120 GB Hidden space in Mojave

Tags: macos, disk-utility, mojave, disk-space

My mac is eating up all free space and I have no clue where it's coming from.  I have used tools like DaisyDisk or OmniDiskSweeper to find any folder/files which might be taking this space, but there are none. Only DaisyDisk is able to see there is 120GB of Hidden space but since I'm using the free trail I'm unable to see what that is.

Here is what I've done so far:

- Disable TimeMachine
- Delete local snapshots
- Checked for mobile backups
- Checked for hibernate file
- Re-index spotlight
- Find big files/folder with tools like DaisyDisk
- Check for errors with first aid in disk utility

All without luck. I've read similar topics on this and tried all what I could find. When I delete an additional 10GB, it' usually eats it up within 1 or 2 days.

[image: DaisyDisk Screencap]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk)

Comment: @fsb some of the steps mentioned here make it look like OP had read that question. like mobile backups, time machine, repair disk etc But better leave it linked here

Comment: Have you checked th size of your Library folder? My library folder has 100 GB but I don't know how to slim it down.

Comment: @ankii, running it right now. But DaisDisk and OmniDiskSweeper are basically the same tools. Will update when it's finished

Comment: @jmh, yes DaisDisk reported it to be 3.6GB

Comment: There are two Library folders. One in your user directory and one above that in the / directory.  Are you sure it listed the correct one?  just checking...

Comment: @jmh, the other one is 17GB.

Comment: @ankii, Disk Inventory is not finding the missing 120GB unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jos  I found out the logs by clicking on the big chunks in decreasing order. I quick looked the files, looked unimportant and deleted them. Hidden or not, you can always remove the unneeded files. Do check on some sites before you delete something you don't know about.

Comment: @ankii, Disk Inventory is not seeing that 120GB, so I'm unable to remove it. I did use that tool to dive deeper into unneeded files/folder/logs, and was able to remove it. However the disk just fils up again with hidden files I'm unable to detect.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the Mac App Store version of DaisyDisk. Download the stand-alone version (https://daisydiskapp.com/downloads/DaisyDisk.zip), it has more features. Then use the "Scan as Administrator" command to reveal the hidden space. Also before scanning make sure you grant DaisyDisk "full disk access", if you're on Mojave or Catalina. To do this, go to DaisyDisk Preferences > Full Disk Access tab and proceed with drag-and-dropping as instructed there.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a solution for this, and since my macbook basically was useless because no space was available anymore I did a clean install