# Hard drive full with 200GB of used space that I can't find

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

All of a sudden I've run out of space. On my **250GB** hard drive, **236GB** is used up with only **13GB** free.

I used Finder to find big files. Nothing significant.

I used tools like Disk Inventory X, OmniDiskSweeper and Purple Tree, but according to them I've only used up **40GB**.

So somehow **200GB** is used up, but I can't see where.

Time Machine isn't running (and never has). The disk has no partitions.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility]

[image: Screenshot of Disk Inventory X]

[image: Screenshot of OmniSweeper]

[image: Screenshot of Purple Tree]

Comment: Related http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/42838

Comment: Try DaisyDisk: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/daisydisk/id411643860?mt=12

Comment: Great suggestion! I just tried DaisyDisk. When I scanned as an admin, I found **187GB** in the hidden ".DocumentsRevisons-V100" folder. It's the Autosave version that it seems OS X has started doing. 

Why did this happen? What's the best way to deal with it? It looks like some people just delete these files, but how do I prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I scanned my drive with DaisyDisk, and as an administrator. ([Instructions](https://daisydiskapp.com/manual/2/en/Topics/AdminScan.html)) I found **187GB** in the hidden "**.DocumentsRevisons-V100**" folder. These are document versions which the OS autosaves ([more info](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202255)). It appears to be from documents primarily from the app Sketch.

[image: Screenshot of DaisyDisk scan]

Here's how I removed the files.

- Open Terminal
- Paste `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` (This makes all hidden files visible)
- Relaunch Finder. You can hold down "Option" and then right click Finder. Click Relaunch.
- Look within the folder **Macintosh HD/.DocumentRevisions-V100/** (For me there were a number of underlining folders with lots of files within.)
- Delete the folders and files within.
- Empty the Trash
- In Terminal paste `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO` . This makes hidden files hidden again.
- Relaunch Finder again. Click the System Apple top left, then "About this Mac" and then "Storage." Breathe a sigh of relief.

[image: Screenshot of hard drive storage]

Here's some articles I referred to:

- https://medium.com/@thomasdegry/how-sketch-took-over-200gb-of-our-macbooks-cb7dd10c8163#.kb2yopebo
- http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/clear-versions-history-auto-save-cache-data-in-mac-os-x/
- https://dribbble.com/shots/2184593-Sketch-users-Free-up-some-space
- https://www.designernews.co/stories/50043-hard-drive-mysteriously-filling-up

Answer (score 1):

I did it the old fashioned way and created a cron job.

```
`#!/usr/bin/env bash 
 export DIRECTORY="/.DocumentRevisions-V100/.cs/ChunkStorage"
 if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Delete file
    rm -rf /.DocumentRevisions-V100/.cs/ChunkStorage/*
 fi`
```

With a cron job to remove at noon.

`crontab -e` 
contents 
`0 12 * * * /bin/bash /SCRIPTS/remove_chunkstorage_sketch.sh`

Comment: Do you mind taking a minute and explaining what your code does and how it answers the question? Some people will not understand what `ChunkStorage` is.

Comment: 1) Checks for the folder in question (the one that stores the versions)                         2) if folder exists, it empties the folder with the versions. I created a cron job to run this every day at noon.

Comment: I'd never run such a script.  Any script with rm and * in it is begging for disaster. A extra blank in the wrong place will be a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve this problem. You can use the built in utility of macOS to see and clear unwanted files, hidden files/folder easily.

Go to the ` > About This Mac` menu on left top, go to storage section and click the `Manage...` button. In the `document` section you can see all the files and folders with their size and delete unwanted files.

Go through [this guide](https://medium.com/@sharath88.05/clearing-hard-disk-space-on-macos-c7bd4eedd55e) for further info.

Comment: That doesn't work for hidden files. In my case the hard drive is almost full (10GB left) but if I look at "about this Mac > documents" nothing big shows up.

Answer (score 0):

##### Failure message

In my case I was doing backup for my iPhone and it failed with error message: **Not enough disk space**.

After this message disappeared 230GB. It was not shown anywhere. Restart did not helped. I did opened MobileSync Backup folder and here was huge folder. I did delete it manually and cleaned trash bin.

##### Backup dir

/Users/<USER_NAME>/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup