# Deleted over 4TB on Promise VTrak, still shows as full

Tags: osx-server, disk-space, raid

This is not a duplicate of [Why is my hard drive still full after deleting files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/why-is-my-hard-drive-still-full-after-deleting-files)

I have of course attempted all methods mentioned there. Via the terminal I can see nothing listed on the drive. I was able to list all the hidden (.named) folders using `ls -a | egrep '^\.'` which then showed me the expected hidden folders, all of which I `sudo rm -rd` I've ran a Verify/Repair with Disk Utility (not sure of the effectiveness on an external RAID) but it had no effect.

I know a solution is just reformat, but what if I had a 10TB RAID and still had multiple terabytes of data? Formatting would not be an option.

This is not a locked files issue, not a trash issue, what seams to be the problem?

How can I free up the (4TB, claimed to still be taken up) space on the empty 5TB Promise VTrak E610f media RAID?

Comment: Why can’t you erase the disk? I did not understand the reason for that.

Comment: @duci9y what do you mean by erase?

Comment: Erase the disk with Disk Utility.

Comment: @duci9y Can you erase only particular data with Disk Utility? I thought it was only entire volumes...which isn't a solution. Like I said, what if I had 10TB of data on the RAID? I just need to clear up mysterious space being taken up.

Comment: Unless, are you referring to "Erase free space"? Unfortunately, that did not work either. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No, I didn’t mean that. I am asking, why can’t you erase the entire volume and start over?

Comment: "I know a solution is just reformat, but what if I had a 10TB RAID and still had multiple terabytes of data? Formatting would not be an option."

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by that, but you have solved your issue, so it doesn’t matter anymore.

Comment: @duci9y Format == erase. You're talking at cross purposes about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a production server so I couldn't be too forceful.

Inevitably, after hours, a reboot resolved the issue. Not my favorite solution by any means.