# Disk Capacity 500 gb falls to 250 gb after deleting files

Tags: hard-drive

I was attempting to free up disk space on my MB Pro - and subsequently deleted most of the iPhoto files & folders as I was constantly receing a 'your start up disk is almost full (e.g. 2.5 gb left out of 499 gb available.

So, having done that, my Hard Drive capacity is now showing only a 250 gb capacity - despite there apparently being a Hard Drive & a SSD each with 250gb.

How can I restore it to its full capacity?

```
Macintosh HD:

  Available:    195.88 GB (195,884,195,840 bytes)
  Capacity: 250.14 GB (250,140,434,432 bytes)
  Mount Point:  /
  File System:  Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: No
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Volume UUID:  1455A0BF-327D-3453-B82F-C2504F6EF7CC
  Physical Drive:
  Media Name:   APPLE SSD SD0256F Media
  Medium Type:  SSD
  Protocol: PCI
  Internal: Yes
  Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  S.M.A.R.T. Status:    Verified
```

Below is the output from `diskutil`:

```
Cathryns-MacBook-Pro:~ cathrynggibson$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 NO NAME                 8.0 GB     disk1s1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.9 GB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 CANON_DC                7.9 GB     disk2s1
```

Comment: SSD - I'm pretty sure - model A1502

Comment: Yest, definitely "
The proprietary SSD is now in a PCIe format, but still isn't a standard drive. Cross your fingers for future compatible drives; for now, you're stuck with what you've got."

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Trim support = yes & yes, it is the Apple original SSD

Comment: It says

The volume Recovery HD appears to be ok.  Volume repair compelte, updating boot support partitions for the volume as required, reviewing boot support loader, checking core storage physical volume partitions, updating windows boot.ini files as required.  The partition map appears to be OK.

Comment: 251 GB APPLE SSD SD0256F Media - in the left panel that's showing on top with Macintosh HD as a sub menu off that, I don't know if that's in any way relevant

Comment: That model is SanDisk SSD with 251 GB max. Where did you get the 500 GB number?

Comment: Sorry, was caught up on the phone  

The Macintosh HD has a capacity of 250.14gb

Comment: The Macintosh HARD DRIVE (250 gb) & the SSD $250gb) = 500gb.  

It always showed up that I had used for example, 492 gb of my available 500gb when I kept getting the startup disk is almost full notice.  And since I deleted the iPhoto files it's telling me I only have 250gb of which I have 5 free gbs

Comment: Will check now - that's the setup of that model - late 2013 - first with the retina screen & SSD

Comment: This computer doesn't contain any PCI cards.

Comment: OK, I deleted all my comments since it is not clear to me what are you talking about! " The proprietary SSD is now in a PCIe format, but still isn't a standard drive. Cross your fingers for future compatible drives; for now, you're stuck with what you've got."

Comment: This is what it is:  

MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.4 13" Late 2013 2.4 GHz Core i5 (I5-4258U)
 
Intro Date: October 22, 2013 Disc Date: July 29, 2014
Order No: ME864LL/A* Model No: A1502 (EMC 2678)
Subfamily: Retina Late 2013 13" Model ID: MacBookPro11,1
Std RAM: 4 GB, 8 GB* Std VRAM: 1 GB*
Std Storage: 128 GB, 256 GB SSD Std Optical: None*

Internal SSD 250gb + Macintosh HD 250gb - brand new straight from the Apple Mac Store

Comment: For me it is simply a matter of misunderstanding. This MBP always was with only SSD, this SSD was named Macintosh HD. There is no HDD inside and never was since there is just no space for it.

Comment: @CathrynG.Gibson What did you pay for the 13"? And does the bill mention the 500 GB SSD? [Apple Shop](http://web.archive.org/web/20131022191248/http://store.apple.com/au/buy-mac/macbook-pro) says 1849 A$ for a 13-inch retina 2.4GHz 256 GB.

Answer (score 1):

You have one SSD (disk0) with 251 GB containing one visible volume 'Macintosh HD' (disk0s2) with a capacity of 250.14 GB of which ~54.3 GB are used and 195.88 GB should be free.

Additionally you have 2 devices attached:

- probably a thumb drive (disk1) with one volume named 'NO NAME' (disk1s1) and the size 8 GB
- a Canon SD-Card (in an attached camera?) (disk2)  with one volume named 'CANON_DC' (disk2s1) and the size 8 GB

If the Finder doesn't show the full free space (195.88 GB) for 'Macintosh HD' or still complains about an 'almost full startup disk' check several answers here at ase:

[Why is my startup disk so full?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162282/why-is-my-startup-disk-so-full)
[Finder Reports Disk is Full, Other Tools Don't Account for it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103029/finder-reports-disk-is-full-other-tools-dont-account-for-it)
[How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Comment: Thankyou for all your help.  I have just spoken to the Apple Mac Store Manager & Chief Technician who has seen my MB Pro & knows that it had 499 gb +/-  He's pretty certain it's a drive failure - he trains other technicians- so he will be running diagnostics on Monday & sorting it out.  

I appreciate everyone's help - many cheers, happy weekend!  Cathryn G. Gibson

Answer (score 1):

Cathryn,

From all the information you've given us, your machine has only a 256 GB SSD. If you believe that it should have had 500 GB, then you should check with Apple. You should be able to get support from them to at least verify the machine details from the following location: https://www.apple.com/support/contact/.

But, to sum up:

- Your Apple Model 1502 machine has room for a single SSD - there is no internal space for a second hard drive.
- This machine was sold with either a 128GB, 256GB or 512GB SSD. Your system is identifying itself as having a 256GB SSD. (APPLE SSD SD0256F Media).

Unfortunately, I do not believe that anyone here will be able to tell you where to find additional space beyond the 256GB that is being reported on your system. Your best bet is with Apple.