# Macbook Pro i7, Hard Disk space filling up before my eyes (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook-pro, disk-space

I have 84GB free on my Flash hard disk but in 3 hours it fills up to 0B.
When I restart the 84GB is there again and something starts eating my HDspace again.

With Grand Perspective it does not show where this space went.
In daisydisk it is in hidden space (also with administrator scan)
On About my Mac, the space went to 'Other'.

It is not the Snapshots of Time machine (I turned TM off).

This thread ([What is filling up my hard drive so fast?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122806/what-is-filling-up-my-hard-drive-so-fast)) did not help me out, so I try again.

Thanks

Comment: Try running `sudo fs_usage -f filesys` and `sudo fs_usage -f diskio` in a Terminal and monitoring the output. Is anything performing a ridiculous amount of write operations?

Comment: I ran this and it's the AvidAppMan Helper (from Avid Media composer) I will delete Avid and see what happens!

Comment: I deleted only the Avid App Man Helper and got my HD space back, great!  But now I want to run this code in terminal again to monitor but can't seem to run it again..

Comment: Ok did a restart and I ran the sudo fs_usage -f filesys again and all good!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help! I will post my solution as an answer for future viewers. Please mark it as correct if it solved your issue!

Answer (score 3):

gvb found the application that kept filling up his drive by running:

`sudo fs_usage -f filesys`

(at my suggestion) in a Terminal. This command allows you to monitor file system usage, such as reads and writes by different processes.

In his case, "Avid App Man Helper" was filling up the drive continuously. Once this application was removed, his hard drive space was freed and no longer being continuously filled by this process.