# "Other" storage in Mac 10.9

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Macbook Pro, 10.9 with 500GB of hard drive storage and 4GB of RAM. When I access the Utility app "System Information", this is what I got.
[image]

There is a yellow block called "Other". What does "other" storage mean in this context?

Comment: Anything that is not Audio, Movies, Photos, Apps or Backup. Which really is a ton of stuff, most probably related to system files.

Comment: @deceze Depends in my case most is not system files but data not in expected directories or application data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 2):

If you look in to the available categories there are files that do not fit in to any.

That is why are they called others.

Nothing wrong with those files, they just did not fit the given categories.

Answer (score 2):

This article is talking about this: [“Other” Storage Space: The big monster of Mac OS X](http://www.theminidrive.com/blogs/theminiblog/116219845-other-storage-space-the-big-monster-of-mac-os-x)

Some examples of the files that may be cataloged as 'Other':

Archives and disk images, including zips, dmg, iso, etc
Personal documents, contacts, calendar data
Items in the OS X folders such as the System folder and caches
App Plugins or extensions
File types not recognized by Spotlight
Documents and file types, including PDF, doc, PSD, etc