# Why Disk Utility full?

Tags: macos, storage

My Disk Utility is full. My Disk is about 1T but now I only have no more 100GB to use.
 I don't think I have used that much, the yellow one is belong to what? I want to erase some files to get more spaces but I have no idea what to do.
I think all of my folder is just 400GB. I think either Application or images, video are duplicate in somewhere. Please help!!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open finder and use the go menu to open your home folder.

- press **command 2** to get the folder list view
- press **command j** and turn on **Calculate all sizes**

Once you know how large these folders are, you can start determining where the "other space" is allocated. I like to sort by size, decreasing so that the biggest users of space bubble up to the top of the window.

Comment: I use a commercial tool called Daisy Disk to show disk utilization... it's very handy for quickly getting an overall recursive picture.

Comment: @mah Yes - Daisy Disk is very good at this. Also WhatSize - I've used the latter for years and years and also started using the former more recently.

Answer (score 1):

Restart holding CMD-R to start from the Recovery partition, and run the Disk Utility from Recovery mode. Do a 'Check Disk' to see if there are any problems - and 'Repair Disk' if it finds any.

IMPORTANT: Make sure you have a backup of your disk before you do this.

Sometimes you can 'find' surprisingly large amounts of free space, by doing this.

Also make sure you always shut down your computer cleanly, and don't press-and-hold the power button to turn it off, EVER.

Comment: Thanks. I think I used to do this 3 times due to my lack of awareness and patient. I will never ever do this again :((((