# Can I search for folders of a certain size (say more than xxx mb)

Tags: macos, finder, search

I am cleaning up a bit. I know how to search for files of a certain size (see below). Is there a way to search for folders above a certain size? Shell commands are ok, but gui is preferred.

To search for files above a certain size:

[image]

If you don't see the "file size" option, select "other", it will be there.

then:

[image]

This is great for files, but it does not include directories/folders. Also, please don't delete files that you do not know what they are for. Some are low level system files and can cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a disk space analyzer application for this purpose, specifically because of the concerns you bring up.

Some options include [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com) (Free to try, Full Version US$9.99) or  [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) (free), [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) (free)

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into those two. In the past, I've bought some apps that are supposed to "clean-up" after deleting programs, but I found those rather unreliable. I presume these are better... Have you used either of them?

Comment: These do a different thing - they just tell you the size of each directory and its sub directories - some e.g. OmniDiskSweeper allow you to delete (not Trash) any selected directory tree see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5360/237 for more

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I've used both, i prefer the way DaisyDisk shows the used space.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for adding OmniDiskSweeper, I've also used that and it works well. But what you've said about DaisyDisk and GrandPerspective is not true. DaisyDisk has a drop location where you can collect unwanted files for deletion. GrandPerspective has a delete button on the toolbar as well.

Comment: Thanks all, I tried almost all of these and loved DaisyDisk. So that's my choice. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this from a terminal window like so:

substitute whatever byte value you're interested in for where I have 100000 below

run this command from the directory you're interested in checking the subdirectory sizes of (from root / if everything)

`du -k * | sort -nr| awk '$1>100000{print}'`

Comment: Thanks Levi, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Would your du command capture system/app files as well? Thanks