# ssd is full on os x

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd, storage

How do I know where the other is and how to remove it? I watched the entire disk, all the files occupy about 50 gigabytes, which could occupy the remaining space on the disk? Please tell me how to fix it? Time machine is off

[image]

Comment: Have a look at: [OS X: What is "other" space in About This Mac?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202867)  -  Also have a look at: [How to Free Up Space Used By Time Machine’s Local Backups on Your Mac](http://www.howtogeek.com/212207/how-to-free-up-space-used-by-time-machines-local-backups-on-your-mac/)

Comment: @user3439894 You should add that as an answer (with a short explanation of what the link says, of course). Also, running Spotlight index might get rid of some of the "Other" and distribute it to each of the other categories.

Comment: @RedEagle2000, I don't have time... getting ready for Christmas Dinner and then when the party is over clean up the mess.  Feel free to do it yourself.

Comment: @user3439894 Nah, I don't want to take credit for your answer. Just post it whenever you can. Merry Christmas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an app like [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) to get a graphical overview of the relative sizes of all items on your system's disks. Often, in a case like yours, there is a forgotten directory with installers around somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm normally not the kind of user to rely on "cleanup" apps, but I will have to say that MacPaw's [CleanMyMac 3](http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) has been wonderful at freeing up space on my computer (Mid-2012 Macbook Pro Retina with stock 256GB SSD). The first time I ran it I cleared out about 22GB of disk space, and I'm regularly removing anywhere from 40MB to 2GB of data cruft a day as of late.