# Why is macOS Sierra taking so much system space? 160+ GB

Tags: macos, filesystem, disk-space

Why is macOS Sierra taking so much system space? 160+ GB for system files?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Comment: @klanomath Not a duplicate because the accepted answer to that linked post *doesn't answer the question*.

Comment: Had the same problem, for me it was the local [time machine backups](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32275206#32275206)

Comment: Sorry, after using DaisyDisk (thanks for the solution at other thread), i just find out that the android sdk take the spaces. <- this answer got deleted