# "Other" in Disk Utility

Tags: disk-utility

The Disk Utility on my Mac shows 100GB of usage by 'Other'.

I had a look inside `~/Library/Caches`, but I did not see anything taking up too much space in there.

[image: Screenshot of '~/Library/Caches']

I even tried using an app called "Clean my Mac". It didn't do much good.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility]

Here is my question: 
How do I find and delete the files that are taking up nearly 100GB of space and are marked as 'other' in Disk Utility.

I am on El Capitan on a 13 inch 2015 MacBook Pro.

Comment: You should create more free space. For a SSD it is better to have at least 25GB ree space. Use an app called Omnidisksweeper, to see what and where are the large files. Delete or move out large files that you do not need on the SSD.

Comment: Yup, that is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Better to get rid of CleanMyMac: a very dangerous scam.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not just 1 file. Other just means it doesn't fit in any of the other categories.

See this answer for more info: [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Comment: Used Omnidisksweeper, Turns out Android System Images are massive:/