# Tag all files required by OS

Tags: filesystem, storage, finder-tag

My hard drive is close to full, so I am trying to delete old and unused files. I am worried that I may delete files that the operating system needs, but I don't recognize. Is there a way to tag all of the files that are required by the system, so I can ignore them while cleaning up storage? I'm thinking in terms of a program or some code you may have made/come across.

Currently using MacOS Sierra version 10.12.4

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: If you have specific files/directories you are unsure about, please add them as a comment or edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS Sierra comes with SIP ([System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)) which protects all important files from getting removed. So an additional tagging is not really necessary.

In finding disk space hogs some of the answers to [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space) might be helpful.