# Free space on volume rapidly disappearing!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd

I have a Samsung SSD 850 EVO installed in February I believe. No problems thus far.

Recently (I'd' say past few days) I noticed my free space going down more than expected. I was at 293 GB free (out of 500 GB total) a few weeks back. Somehow yesterday I was in the mid 100s (around 150, say) remaining. Several hours ago I was at 95.63 GB remaining. Right now, I am at 65.93 GB remaining! Worried I would be able to operate soon.

Does anyone know anything about why or how this is happening and/or how I can stop and subsequently reverse the trend?

Comment: In case I should make clear, no I don't do heavy video-watching or editing (I downloaded a few hundred megabytes worth for some instruction purposes earlier this week).

Comment: Probably related: 1. [Free space on hard drive going up and down too much](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286583/free-space-on-hard-drive-going-up-and-down-too-much/286605#286605) 2. [How to wipe huge .MobileBackups folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85805/how-to-wipe-huge-mobilebackups-folder)

Comment: I ran disk expert and found a series of folders beginning with about 170gb in it but it's private and I can't access the info of it or its subordinate folders. Thoughts on this?

Comment: You have to run the tool with admin privileges - if possible. Else: install [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) (iirc 7-day full functional trial) and run it as admin. Then make a screenshot of the result (shift-cmd-4, then space bar: choose DisyDisk window) and add it to your question.

Comment: So the jist of the solution turned out to be: restart computer. Back up to 240-some GB free. Much better. I guess, if anyone can tell me, I'd like to know wjhy I've had this computer for several years and nothing like this has happened before. Is this specifically a symptom of having an SSD or does it happen to HDD users as well? If the latter is true, what is it that simply grown to a size unable to withstand being powered on and required professional service (or at least required something more in-depth for me than a simple restart?)?

Comment: Please add a second question with some details (i.e. which folders/files are growing and shrinking like mad). The culprits in the first link provided in my first comment were gradle, IDEA and iTerm2 caches.