# What is a free alternative to something like Daisy Disk, for finding out what is hogging your MacBook hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, software-recommendation, macos

I suddenly lost a bunch of hard drive space...Has anyone had good success with a FREE [Daisy Disk](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/daisydisk/id411643860?l=en&mt=12) alternative that graphically shows the disk usage that you can recommend? Thx.

Comment: Have a look at: [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) - "Download GrandPerspective from Sourceforge for free or from the App Store for $1.99. You'll get the same app either way. So what's the difference? When you get it from the App Store you know that it has passed Apple's review and quality control, you help cover distribution costs and you support further development."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For years I have used [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more).

It is free, and shows your files in a column view, sorted by size. It’s very easy to use and fast (well, as fast as your HD or SSD allows :-)

Comment: Thank you. Apparently my question sucks...can I delete it? I am getting a message that I cannot.

Comment: @Sizzle I guess I see their reasons for putting it on hold, but IMO these questions can be helpful. Don't sweat it.

Comment: The question doesn't "suck;" it's considered off-topic because you're simply asking for a software recomendation.  What needs to be on on you part is to *describe* what you want the software to solve (screenshots are helpful) and what *research you've done thus far.*  It was this lacking info/effort as to why it was put on hold.