# Can I safely remove these MOV files from the OSX SSD?

Tags: icloud, mojave, disk-space

It is my 'Macintosh HD Info':

[image]

However from time to time I get this 'There is not enough disk space available to install the product.'.

So I really want to free up some space.

I also use the 'CleanMyMac 3' to identify the files to remove.

It suggests these large files:

[image]

**My questions are**

1. How can I make OSX to start the purging process?
2. I hesitate to remove those MOV files because I am not sure if it will also remove them from my iCloud Photos library. The warning from CleanMyMac is quite dire: "Are you sure you want to permanently remove "IMG_3627.MOV"? You can't undo this action."

I certainly do not want to remove it from my photo library. I just want to remove the local copy so I can free more space.

So is there a safe way to reclaim the local space without removing the MOV files from icloud?

**EDIT:**

1. I have already used the 'Optimise Mac Storage' option

[image]

Comment: Have you set "optimise storage" for photos? On a side note, grab tools like DaisyDisk or disk inventory X and look for giant log files etc. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space/5360#5360

Comment: I use 'optimise storage' in Photos

Answer (score 1):

If CleanMyMac is going to remove the files from their present location, then yes, they will be removed from your Photos Library.

You would be better off going to "About This Mac" under the apple menu, and on the Storage tab, click "Manage". Then click on "Store in iCloud", and select Photos.

[image]

As a general rule, I avoid all apps that claim to 'clean', 'purge', 'sweep' or otherwise perform housekeeping, as they often can have unintended consequences.

Comment: Thx for the answer but I have already enabled these options since I started using this MBP (almost 2 years)