# How to disable terminal cache?

Tags: terminal

I see these message. Which means that terminal uses some disk cache. How to disable it using disk caches? Thanks.

"Your disk space is critially low."

Older terminal scrollback contents may be automatically discarded to conserve VM backing store".

Comment: If you disk space is low, the terminal scrollback buffer most probably isn't the main issue.

Comment: Probably related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space