# What is Catalina (and no other OSX) doing with/to the disk?

Tags: macos, catalina, disk-space, virtual-memory

My question is at
[Mysterious disappearance of disk space on Catalina (and not any other OSX)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396001/mysterious-disappearance-of-disk-space-on-catalina-and-not-any-other-osx)

Tetsujin closed it pointing to [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)
but just look at the very different O.S.s in the two questions.

Also, my question is vastly different in that I have expressly identified that the Case of the Vanishing Disk-Space is solely attributable to Catalina as no such thing was happening in Sierra, and there are also further particulars stated in the question.

In one line, What on earth is Catalina doing with and to the disk that other OSXs didn't?

With due respect to 'One-Percenters' of apple.stackexchange, please try to read and understand the question and its specifics and don't keep being so trigger-happy in shutting down questions/threads/discussions.

Comment: Two remarks on this: a) the linked question shows how you can identify what‘s consuming disk space on your system, independently of the macOS version installed

Comment: b) It might very well be that this is not the answer you were expecting. In that case please don‘t repost the question. Edit your first question instead, show/mentioned what you‘ve already tried and why this (not the answers in the linked Q&A) doesn’t answer your question.

Comment: And, after reading your original question again: the Q&A explaining how to find what it slowly eating your disk space seems to be spot on. We can‘t see your system, so you can only check yourself. Having said that, I also would recommend a reboot as some caches etc may only get cleared at boot time.