# MacBook Air 2015 1465 Catalina 10.15.6 Update Fail!

Tags: catalina, install, software-update, restart

I am using 128gb MacAir 1465 2015 version. I have XCode and some other apps. When I try to update my mac. It looks like completely fine. I click Update Now button and it requests restart but that is the gimmick. With hope I look on to my screen after clicking restart button it perfectly reboots and yet i get same warning about the same update. It is like edge of tomorrow movie. please help me !!

Comment: Try running `softwareupdate -i -a` in the Terminal.

Comment: it requires 12.36 gb disk space. is there any other way?

Comment: You need to free-up space on your laptop.  Try moving some large files off temporarily until after the update completes.  You can see some software that will help you identify the large files on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space).

Comment: Thank you all. It works finally. I just used sudo and added --restart latter