# Other Mac storage taking up 90GB! Help!

Tags: mac, storage

I currently have other storage around 90GB on a 120GB internal drive so pretty much all of it. I have optimised to iCloud and deleted all large extra files and documents etc. However, on the omnidisksweeper it is showing there is 20gb just in updates and 13gb on system but I am unsure what I can delete. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my drive space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space)

Answer (score 0):

I woudn't be concerned too much with those two since they are only 33 gigs total. The 90 GB space should be of more concern. I suggest you get [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com) or [Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) to give you a color graphical mapping of your disk drive. These color maps make it easy to see what is hogging your disk drive. Daisey Disk, if obtained from developers site has a free trial.  Grand Perspective is free.
I'm not familar with omnidisksweeper.

Comment: OmniDiskSweeper is the granddaddy of disk browsers, made by Omni Group (OmniOutliner, etc). It orders the whole drive by size, allowing you to drill down, identify, and delete large files. It's just as good as the others you mention.

Comment: @benwiggy  - thanks.  i've heard of Omnidisksweeper but have never used it.  This kind of makes my answer redundent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Updates pending, then installing them should remove the packages.

13Gb for the system is to be expected - don't delete anything from there!

Check for iPhone/iPad backups, which get stored in your user Library. You can manage and delete them in iTunes.