# Does anyone REALLY knows what does Other actually contains on a Mac and how to clear it?

Tags: macos, ssd, memory, storage

Please, don't mark this post as a duplicate! I already checked all the same posts about this topic on this website and can say that all answers really answer nothing.
I have 256gb SSD, and 85 (!!!) of them are in the Other storage. It is ridiculous. Those files don't exist. I already used OmniDiskSweeper - it does not show those files. It shows only 135gb and that's all, yep. 20gb for MaOS and other 85 are just gone forever. Don't suggest me using CleanMyMac please, I used it, it cleaned 1 Gb of junk files, clearly not 85... It seems that there is no point of buying 256 and for the next Mac I'll have to buy 512

Comment: Which Mac and which macOS? Are you running Time Machine? If so, it could be local backups.

Comment: This post **will most likely** still be downvoted or even closed because you should: give much more detail about your system (as mentioned by @lhf), clarify what posts exactly you have read and most importantly tell us exactly what steps you have done so far. And it is hard to not mark this as a duplicate if you don't even specify what would be different from your question to others, if you basically tell us nothing. -1

Comment: @lhf Hi. No, I don't use Time Machine at all. Macbook Air 2015, the latest Big Sur

Comment: @X_841 I said that all other answers were - use DiskSweeper and CleanMyMac and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Other == Miscellaneous.

It isn't a single category, it's everything left after the categorisable data has been accounted for. You will not find it all in one convenient pile in a corner of your drive, waiting patiently for you to consign it to the Trash.

I would still consider the answers to [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space) would be your best method to tackle this dilemma.