# Is there a way to view just symbolic links that I've created?

Tags: icloud, finder, symlink

I've noticed my iCloud storage is full even though I only have roughly ~2GB of data in there. When I view my iCloud storage I notice that both my desktop and my documents seem to be listed twice - once on the sidebar under 'iCloud' and also within the 'iCloud Drive' itself:

[image]

Is this normal? Or have I tried to be clever and add a symbolic link to these folders, even though I didn't need to?

Thanks )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is completely normal when you have chosen to sync your Desktop & Documents folders with iCloud Drive. It does not mean that those folders would be stored twice or take up twice the space in iCloud Drive.

Comment: That’s really reassuring to know, thank you! Now I just need to figure out where the storage is being used then.

Comment: @Nick, if you go to System Preferences > iCloud > Manage, doesn't it show you how the space is used?

Comment: OmniDiskSweeper or other apps from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space/5359#5359

Comment: Thanks @LSpice yes it does, but it says it’s using 4.8GB when the entire data in the folder is only 1.4GB