# The other part of my Mac hard disk is full?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, time-machine, mac-appstore

On my MacBook, I only have 250GB and out of this 250GB my MacBook is taking up 129GB in the other section.

I looked everywhere to the best of my knowledge.

Please note my home directories is only 45GB.

Can you here somehow please help me?
[image]

This question [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space) does not answer my question.

Comment: What does it show you when you hit `manage`? You didn't tell us but: Did you go through finder and search for big large files? You could turn on show hidden files in finder (open finder window and hit `cmd` + `shift` + `.`) and then start your search at Macintosh HD, select all folders and hit `cmd` + `I`. You will see how much space each directory takes up. Go through them and check where the files are located.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAC why the other part of my hard disk is completely full?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411747/mac-why-the-other-part-of-my-hard-disk-is-completely-full)

Comment: Don’t re-post your questions, **edit the original question** with exact details to clarify your problem.