# Why Other storage keeps increasing when I don't download anything on this laptop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, storage

I cleaned my `Macbook Pro` about 2 months ago, I deleted plenty of non useful files and junk and I made about 100 gb free.

After this I use this laptop only for browsing web, watch youtube and write some code on my personal project (rarely), but `Other` storage keeps increasing day by day, I don't understand what is using the space and where it comes from, I'm getting crazy about it.

I don't want to go through hundreds of folders and guess what is useful and what can be deleted again, It will waste considerable amount of my time, so what might be the solution here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: All those cache files from websites?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know where from, that's my question

Comment: Do you happen to have Time Machine backups enabled, but haven't connected the backup drive in a while?

Comment: @jksoegaard righr now time machien isn't enabled, but I don't remember was it enabled in the past or not, how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with two things.

1. Power down the Mac at night, connect to a charger if it's portable then when you log in - hold the shift key to ensure no apps open. Let it go to sleep normally. I would enable Power Nap, too for a few days of this to let the scheduled maintenance run a couple nights.
2. Boot to recovery mode and repair the entire disk and then repair the Data / Macintosh HD items in Disk Utility.

If you still have high storage - then use the Manage to look at the largest files and see if they make sense and consider updating the macOS as new as you can stand after making a backup and before updating.

If you prefer a third party tool, check out [Daisy Disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20168/5472).