# macOS — What is the reason for a 6 Gb Dropbox folder to use 107 Gb of space?

Tags: macos, big-sur, storage, dropbox

My whole Dropbox folder contains just around 6 (six!) Gb of data. It's the same amount of space on all my PCs, but on my MacBook these are 107 (hundred seven!) Gb for some reason. I'd like to find this reason as well as a some kind of a solution for this problem.

I'm using Dropbox 121.3.4266 on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

**Update:** I've uninstalled Dropbox client, deleted the local Dropbox folder and have reinstalled Dropbox again. At the moment `du -sh Dropbox` returns just 6,3G, so the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: How have you diagnosed that it is 107 GB on the Mac?

Comment: Just the usual way: using folder info.

Comment: @georgmierau that may be wrong. Try a disk analyzer like ones given at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space or command `du` with appropriate flags of course.

Comment: OK you now have said macOS says Dropbox is 107G but why do you think it should be 6G What does du (or easier one of the GUI tools) say is taking up the space

Comment: Hi @georgmierau, I'm glad you figured out how to solve this issue. It'd be great if you added the text in your update as an answer and marked it as accepted. This shows other people your question has a useful answer and will help others that have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox, OneDrive, iCloud and other could sync programs often show different sizes on one file. You want to check a few files to look at the size on disk as well as the settings about saving space / dehydrating files / optimizing storage before trusting any one tool to measure on disk allocation.

I use `ncdu` on Macs where I have homebrew running or `du -s /path/to/folder` to double check things. Finder and even Apple’s system information don’t always tell the true story with cloud files.

You can also get a good measure by using Time Machine to back up the folder and checking size there.

Assuming you are actually that far off, the fix would be to boot to recovery and run disk utility one time on the drive to correct and detect any accounting errors, then potentially uninstalling the sync app to clean up the folder.

Comment: du -sh Dropbox returns 96G.

Comment: Is that du on your backup of the files or on the live system? @georgmierau

Comment: It was my Dropbox folder on my Mac. The same folder on my PC was (and is) 6 GB (still).