# Terminal command to delete unnecessary logs

Tags: terminal, disk-space, macos, logs

Avast antivirus says that my mac running Mojave has 1.25 GB of "unnecessary logs":

[image: Avast notification about unnecessary logs]

The Avast website does not provide information about their meaning.

What are they? How can I delete them with on the Terminal command-line?

Comment: I would ask Avast what they mean. Without clarification, I'm not sure I would trust Avast's definitions. Caches don't go off like fish, and the necessity of logs is subjective at best. I would just delete your trash and be done with it. (You could also save space by deleting Avast, of course.)  ;-)

Comment: I asked at: https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=289671.0

Answer (score 4):

My guess is they want to sell you a paid cleanup product so this is the call to action.

- https://www.avast.com/cleanup

Instead of using a third party tool, I would first make sure you are happy with Apple recommendations on disk clean up.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996

Your storage is likely SSD and the data stays written and only gets purged when needed by the OS so stale cache seems a misnomer and the same goes for log files. Those should rotate and Apple tools or [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com/) give me a much better idea where the space is used if I need to take action.

- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

The terminal command I use to **engage the clean up of stale files and secure, patch and update** my Mac is

```
softwareupdate —-all —-install —-restart
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the Terminal command has some 'side-effects', like installing any OS upgrades pending!

Comment: Yes, secure means apply all patches! Downloaded patches and lack of restart can cause cleanup jobs to stick, it’s not common, but can be all that’s needed @benwiggy thanks for improving the answer with a great comment.

Comment: @bmike Patches are in --recommended, not --all.