# How to inspect the 'Other' category of storage without installing anything

Tags: macos, big-sur, storage

In Apple menu > About This Mac > Storage > Manage... the "Other" category is greyed out and I cannot see what is occupying it.

How can I inspect the parts of the system and files that are filling up the Other category without using a third-party GUI storage explorer app?

Comment: In the duplicate the end of this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5360/237 includes a way using du. Basically that answer covers all the known options