# MacOS "Manage Storage" usage information does not add up

Tags: storage

My computer is running out of storage so I used `Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage...`

to pull up the interface to help me audit and remove unneeded files.

But the numbers do not match the files in the list. For example, it says I have 94 GB of "Documents" but the File Browser only shows ~4-5 GB worth of folders when you sum up their totals.

[image]

This is different from [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space) because although that offers tools to help free up storage it does not explain inconsistencies in apples Manage Storage feature.

Comment: Please edit your post to be specific about what the question is here. Also keep in mind that „why“ questions are often hard to answer, we prefer questions which focus on a practical problem.

Comment: I think my practical technical problem is clear as written. I don’t understand what this MacOS user interface is communicating. The numbers should add up unless I’m misunderstanding it. Is it an Apple bug? Do they intend to fix it? Or is this interface not intended for this use case?