# How can I order all files and directories by last access date?

Tags: macos, big-sur

How can I sort all files and directories on my harddrive in order of most recent access?

Access by myself or by a program.

I would like to see the old stuff I have lying around that just doesn't get used.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort"? Do you want to change sort order in Finder, or when running `ls` in Terminal, or something else?

Comment: @nohillside I just want to see which parts of my file system are most unused

Comment: I assume this is about file in your User directory then?

Comment: CleanMyMac X is good for this type of search, or look at things by size, maybe - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Comment: @nohillside no it's about files everywhere

Comment: `man ls` then :-)

Answer (score 3):

Open a new finder window with CMD+n.  If it doesn't default to "Recents" - choose it.  Hit the cog, and choose "Show Search Criteria".

[image: choose "show search criteria"]

This takes you to a "Raw query" (other views will also do the same - I just use this as it's not grouped), choose to view by "list";

[image: choose list option]

This enables the column headings, which you can now use to affect the sorting order.  Just click on "Date Last Opened" until it sorts by oldest first;

[image: Sort by "date last opened" oldest first]

And ... that's it!  Obviously, it won't care about files you've never opened but that's fine.  TBH, I use CleanMyMac for this type of thing, as it builds an index so you can sort by various attributes (e.g. file size is a good one) very easily.

Comment: Recents seems to only show my Documents? I can't see any system or application files in it

Comment: It's because you don't as a user "open" these files, they list as "--" for the last opened date, which you'll see if you change the raw query string to; (kMDItemFSName="*.*")

Comment: But I would like to find out about last "access by myself _or_ by a program"

Comment: That’s the change to “all files” which I mentioned in my previous post above.

Comment: I do not see where you mentioned all files previously.

Comment: Hmmm maybe it's implied as I've replied to you - but "all files" is when you change the raw query string to; (kMDItemFSName=".")