# System data storage is huge

Tags: macos, storage

The system data on my mac is taking more than 110GB of space. Is this normal?
[image: Apple Storage view]

The ~/Library/Containers folder is 64G. Can I delete this folder?

**Edit:**
I installed OmnidiskSwiper, Its tells me that the folder Library has 110GB, but than show my only 12.5GB + 1.4GB. I don't understand where the files are.

[image]

Comment: First get a more detailed view from the answers here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space

Comment: The basic answer is no you can't delete from there as that is where sandboxed apps (which include many Apple apps and from the App Store)  store their data

Comment: Have you emptied the bin?

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a comment to the original question but is an answer to why OmniDiskSweeper is not showing the full size of the Library folder. This really should be a different question.

The + by a directory size means that OmniDiskSweeper can't read all of it. You need to give it Full Disk Access

From OmniDiskSweeper 1.14 release notes

> OmniDiskSweeper 1.14 now displays an indication of sizes which are incomplete due to system protections or file permission constraints. This release is a macOS Universal app, which can run natively on both M1-powered Macs and Intel-based Macs running macOS 11 Big Sur or later.

...

> Incomplete Size Indicator — When OmniDiskSweeper cannot fully read the contents of a file or directory (due to system protections or file permissions), it places a + sign next to its size to indicate that the reported value is an incomplete, minimum value rather than the total size. (For example, a size of “1.8 GB+” indicates that the content OmniDiskSweeper was able to access was 1.8 GB, but there was additional content which OmniDiskSweeper was unable to read.) Incomplete sizes will always be sorted above complete sizes, since there’s no telling how large that content actually is.

> To grant OmniDiskSweeper access to any files the current user can read, open Security Preferences in System Preferences, choose Full Disk Access, and add the OmniDiskSweeper app. (OmniDiskSweeper needs Full Disk Access to be able to scan your entire disk—otherwise, it can’t scan for files in your Trash among other locations. Information collected by OmniDiskSweeper is only used for the results displayed to you within the app; we do not track or store that data for use by anyone else anywhere else.)

> To grant OmniDiskSweeper access to files not readable by the current user, open Terminal and use sudo to run OmniDiskSweeper as the root superuser. (To grant access to all files on your Mac, you’ll also need to grant Full Disk Access as noted above, since even the root superuser cannot access all files otherwise.) When doing this, please note that any files you trash from the app will go to root’s Trash (in ~root/.Trash) rather than the current user’s Trash.

The last point is not relevant here but is worrying as this was not needed before

Comment: The same situation re. full disk access is true when using Daisy Disk. In that case it's also recommended to use the version d/l from their website rather than the App Store version, which won't allow full disk access. IIRC, if you buy on the App Store then the unrestricted version comes free. I have sorted out a similar problem to OP using DD, and as I suggested above, due to forgetting to check the Bin.

Comment: It will be true for all apps (or command line tools) that read all directories.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's classification of file types here is quite broad, and not always accurate; but clearly something is using a lot of space.

As mentioned in this article: [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my drive space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space)
I would use something like OmniDiskSweeper to investigate what's using up all that space.

I wouldn't delete ALL of `~/Library/Containers`, but I'd certainly have a look what sub-folder is eating it up.

Comment: I tried  OmniDiskSweeper and I am still confused. I updated the post with more info

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the things others have mentioned I found that /opt/homebrew/var/log had over 90GB of logs in there which was all lumped in with the "System Data" category