# System storage space keeps increasing on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, storage, ventura

I am running a macOS 13 Ventura on a 3-month-old MacBook Air M2. It was all fine until I upgraded to Ventura. But once I did, I started noticing an increase in the amount of storage space the system storage is taking up. I wasn't paying much heed to it initially, but recently I noticed it had climbed up to 100GB from something around 30GB. I googled quite a bit and came across a few articles claiming it might be alright after a few Ventura updates. This was a couple of days ago. Now, it has gone up to 175GB. I'm new to the "Apple ecosystem" and this has left me completely clueless. I really hope someone could help me find a way out of this.

[image: Screenshot of the drive space allocation from About This Mac]

Comment: See these other questions/answers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261252/system-storage-on-macos-sierra-is-470gb https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450402/system-data-storage-is-huge/450403#450403