# an app that tells what changed on a disk

Tags: applications, storage

Is there any app that will tell what made a Mac's disk storage grow or shrink? It seems like every week or so, Finder shows my available storage has jumped or shrunk by more than a few GBs. Yesterday, it went from around 100GB free to about 3! That was an emergency, and yet I knew of no quick way to tell what caused it. The culprit turned out be the huge default cache of a newly installed app, Mountain Duck. But it took a few minutes to figure that out. There must be a quick way to see what caused such a jump.

Comment: Your drive's contents may change several times a second, all day, every day. Something like this would bury you in useless data.

Comment: Micromanaging storage in this manner is not effective as @Tetsujin already mentioned.  What you need to look at is upgrading your storage, if you’re over 50% usage, it’s time to think about getting more.  If you’re above 80%, you need more storage now.  If you’re worried about the remaining 100GB of space, you’re about 1/2 TB too late.

Comment: You don't need a third party app - but [I'll link this to a thread with the "native solution" that I proposed there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146651/5472) as well as many third party apps.