# Mac High Sierra huge disk space usage discrepancy

Tags: macos, high-sierra, disk-space

Upgraded my macbook pro 2012 laptop from Mountain Lion to High Sierra recently.
Now the 256G SSD continues to run out of space.
DU shows 127G used.

Yet Finder and System info show 255G used. I have timemachine local snapshots turned off. In fact I have tm turned off.

> tmutil listlocalsnapshots /

returns nothing

I have rebuilt the system Spotlight indexes multiple times, shutdown multiple times, removed chrome, removed everything that I can, but to no avail.
I can live with it except some apps use that system info and won't let me download or start new documents because of only megabytes remaining.

Looking at [other posts](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8090544?answerId=32537764022#32537764022) I did have a problem with a backup that took forever and I interrupted. The linked post indicates that in /Volumes the TM had a huge backup image. My /Volumes has a symbolic link to Macintosh HD. This doesn't seem correct to me.

```
sh-3.2# cd /Volumes
sh-3.2# ls -la 
total 0 
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel 96 Sep 13 14:14 . 
drwxr-xr-x  30 root  wheel  960 Sep  6 09:32 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 Sep 13 14:14 Macintosh HD -> /
```

Sorry no screenshots, cuz no space to do so!!

Hope someone can help. If it is as simple as moving forward to a newer version, please let me know.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C51.3130